# Super Blue Fire / Super Ultimate Sacred Fire

Tags: crash-team-racing-nitro-fueled

On some tracks the blue fire (USF) you get from turbopads differ in speed. There is [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9kym2OtcKc) explaining this and sums up the following tracks:

- Thunder Struck (Turbo pad after the U-turn)
- Deep Sea Driving (The left turbo pad before the kraken)
- Hyper Spaceway (Turbo pad before the finish line)
- Twilight Tour (Turbo pad after the wooden ramp jump)

And in the description/comments:

- Tiny Temple (Turbo pad before the finish line)

I think Hot Air Skyway has also this better version of blue fire (USF). My question is, are there any more turbo pads that add on this list?

Comment: I'm going to comment instead of answer because I'm not 100% sure on this. But on the new Prehistoric Playground track, I think the first Blue Fire pad might be a "super" one whereas the last is not. In an online game I had someone fly past me when we were both speed characters as I was maintaining the blue flame from the final pad before the end of the lap whereas he must have kept the one from the start of the lap all the way through.

Comment: My idea is that the blue turbopads kinda stack if you get more than one in the same lap and keeping it, giving you a more powerful blue fire. This seems true, because every "special" blue turbopad listed is placed right after a "normal" blue turbopad (in Deep Sea Driving I'm counting the one before the goal). Further tests are needed, for example losing the first blue fire and only taking the super blue turbopad and see what happens.